# Unable to save java melody logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-melody

Trying to retain(save) java melody logs as they the /temp gets cleared during container restart.

1. Have tried relocating the log file location to other location (works fine on local), but on server this doesn't work.
2. Also  tried moving files to another remote location and try to replace them in temp after container restart, server does not pick them up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to save files within a container is not the way to go if you want to retain your javamelody logs.

Javamelody has a detailed [guide](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#optional-centralization-server-setup) on how to setup a centralized server for log retention

Comment: Yes centralized collect server is a possible way, but it is considered optional. To keep it simple it is recommended in general to use the monitoring from the webapp without a centralized collect server.

Answer (score 0):

You may retain javamelody data between container restarts by persisting it.

For example, with a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) in Docker, I use myself in docker-compose.yml something like :

```yaml
services:
  mywebapp:
    image: "mywebapp:latest"
    volumes:
      - javamelody_mywebapp:/tmp/javamelody
volumes:
  javamelody_mywebapp:
```